# opencv - image multiplication

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, multiplication

hi, i'm trying to play a little bit with Mat class.
I want to do a product element wise between two images, the c++/opencv port of MATLAB [immultiply](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/images/ref/immultiply.html).

This is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat imgA, imgB;
Mat imgAB;
Mat product;

void printMinMax(Mat m, string s) {
    double minVal; 
    double maxVal; 
    Point minLoc; 
    Point maxLoc;

    minMaxLoc( m, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc );
    cout << "min val in " << s << ": " << minVal << endl;
    cout << "max val in " << s << ": " << maxVal << endl;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {

    cout << "OpenCV version: " << CV_MAJOR_VERSION << " " << CV_MINOR_VERSION << endl;

    imgA = imread("test1.jpg"); 
    cout << "original image size: " << imgA.rows << " " << imgA.cols << endl;
    cout << "original type: " << imgA.type() << endl;
    cvtColor(imgA, imgA, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    printMinMax(imgA, "imgA");

    imgB = imread("test2.jpg"); 
    cout << "original image size: " << imgB.rows << " " << imgB.cols << endl;
    cout << "original type: " << imgB.type() << endl;
    cvtColor(imgB, imgB, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    printMinMax(imgB, "imgB");

    namedWindow("originals", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("product", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imgAB = Mat( max(imgA.rows,imgB.rows), imgA.cols+imgB.cols, imgA.type());
    imgA.copyTo(imgAB(Rect(0, 0, imgA.cols, imgA.rows)));
    imgB.copyTo(imgAB(Rect(imgA.cols, 0, imgB.cols, imgB.rows)));

    product = imgA.mul(imgB);
    printMinMax(product, "product");

    while( true )
    {
        char c = (char)waitKey(10);

        if( c == 27 )
            { break; }

        imshow( "originals", imgAB );
        imshow( "product", product );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

here is the result:

```
OpenCV version: 2 4
original image size: 500 500
original type: 16
min val in imgA: 99
max val in imgA: 255
original image size: 500 500
original type: 16
min val in imgB: 0
max val in imgB: 255
init done 
opengl support available 
min val in product: 0
max val in product: 255
```

I think that max value in the product has to be greater than 255, but is truncated to 255 because the type of the two matrixes is 16.
I have tried to convert the matrixes to CV_32F but the maxVal in the product is 64009 (a number that i don't understand)

Comment: Try first a small 3x1 and 1x3 Matrix and see if you are doing the right multiplications.

Comment: yeah, nice advice. anyway i want to make elementwise multiplications, not matrix product, so i think that the 2 mat needs to be of equal size

Comment: Just making sure that you are doing the correct product. You must not be doing something 1x255 and expecting a different result other than 255.

Comment: Oh one more thing mate :) Try initializing 'product' matrix, I dont know if your image is color or not, but might be the type is CV_8UCx which would truncate your results. Check the type and then initialize

Comment: thanks a lot mate! now "how things works" is more clear, see my own answer!

Comment: Glad that you were lead to the light :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Wajih](https://stackoverflow.com/users/349026/wajih) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175114/opencv-image-multiplication#comment19642872_14175114) i have done some basic test, and some basic debug, and i got i work perfectly. I think this could become a mini tutorial on alpha blending and image multiply, but for now is only a few lines of commented code.

note that the 2 images must be of the same size.. and for sure some error checking should be done for a solid code..

Hope it helps someone! And, of course, if you have some hints to make this code more readable or more compact (one-liner guys are very appreciate!) or efficient.. just comment, thank you a lot!

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void printMinMax(Mat m, string name) {
    double minVal; 
    double maxVal; 
    Point minLoc; 
    Point maxLoc;

    if(m.channels() >1) {
        cout << "ERROR: matrix "<<name<<" must have 1 channel for calling minMaxLoc" << endl;
    }

    minMaxLoc( m, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc );
    cout << "min val in " << name << ": " << minVal << " in loc: " << minLoc << endl;
    cout << "max val in " << name << ": " << maxVal << " in loc: " << maxLoc << endl;
}

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {

    cout << "OpenCV version: " << CV_MAJOR_VERSION << " " << CV_MINOR_VERSION << endl; // 2 4

    Mat imgA, imgB;
    Mat imgAB;
    Mat product;

    // fast matrix creation, comma-separated initializer
    // example1: create a matrix with value from 0 to 255
    imgA = Mat(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
    imgA = (Mat_<uchar>(3,3) << 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,255);
    cout << "test Mat 3x3" << endl << imgA << endl;

    // not that if a value exceed 255 it is truncated at value%256 
    imgA = (Mat_<uchar>(3,3) << 0,1, 258 ,3,4,5,6,7,255);
    cout << "test Mat 3x3 with last element truncated to 258%256=2" << endl << imgA << endl;

    // create a second matrix
    imgB = Mat(3, 3, CV_8UC1);
    imgB = (Mat_<uchar>(3,3) << 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

    // now the matrix product. we are multiplying a value that can goes from 0-255 with another 0-255 value..
    // the edge cases are "min * min" and "max * max", 
    // that means: our product is a function that return a value in the domain 0*0-255*255 ; 0-65025
    // ah, ah! this number exceed the Mat U8C1 domain!, we need different data types. 
    // we need a bigger one.. let's say 32FC1 

    Mat imgA_32FC1 = imgA.clone();
    imgA_32FC1.convertTo(imgA_32FC1, CV_32FC1);
    Mat imgB_32FC1 = imgB.clone();
    imgB_32FC1.convertTo(imgB_32FC1, CV_32FC1);

    // after conversion.. value are scaled?
    cout << "imgA after conversion:" << endl << imgA_32FC1 << endl;
    cout << "imgB after conversion:" << endl << imgB_32FC1 << endl;

    product = imgA_32FC1.mul( imgB_32FC1 );
    // note: the product values are in the range 0-65025
    cout << "the product:" << endl << product << endl;

    // now, this does not have much sense, because we started from a 0-255 range Mat and now we have a 0-65025 that is nothing..
    // it is not uchar range and it is not float range (that is a lot bigger than that)
    // so, we can normalize back to 0-255
    // what do i mean with 'normalize' now?
    // i mean: scale all values for a constant that maps 0 to 0 and 65025 to 255..
    product.convertTo(product, CV_32FC1, 1.0f/65025.0f * 255);
    // but it is still a 32FC1.. not as the start matix..
    cout << "the product, normalized back to 0-255, still in 32FC1:" << endl << product << endl;
    product.convertTo(product, CV_8UC1);
    cout << "the product, normalized back to 0-255, now int 8UC1:" << endl << product << endl;

    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------" << endl;

    // real stuffs now.
    imgA = imread("test1.jpg"); 
    cvtColor(imgA, imgA, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    imgB = imread("test2.jpg"); 
    cvtColor(imgB, imgB, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    imgA_32FC1 = imgA.clone();
    imgA_32FC1.convertTo(imgA_32FC1, CV_32FC1);
    imgB_32FC1 = imgB.clone();
    imgB_32FC1.convertTo(imgB_32FC1, CV_32FC1);

    product = imgA_32FC1.mul( imgB_32FC1 );
    printMinMax(product, "product");
    product.convertTo(product, CV_32FC1, 1.0f/65025.0f * 255);
    product.convertTo(product, CV_8UC1);

    // concat two images in one big image
    imgAB = Mat( max(imgA.rows,imgB.rows), imgA.cols+imgB.cols, imgA.type());
    imgA.copyTo(imgAB(Rect(0, 0, imgA.cols, imgA.rows)));
    imgB.copyTo(imgAB(Rect(imgA.cols, 0, imgB.cols, imgB.rows)));

    namedWindow("originals", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("product", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while( true )
    {
        char c = (char)waitKey(10);

        if( c == 27 )
            { break; }

        imshow( "originals", imgAB );
        imshow( "product", product );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you should convert your matrices imgA, imgB to say CV32FC1 type. Since the max values in this matrices is 255, the maximum possible value is 65025. However, the maximum at imgA and imgB may not be in the same location, so 64009 is quite possible.