# OpenCV masking/split function

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a question for us. I'm a newbe of OpenCV and I need to understand if that lib can help me to reach my goals.

I need to use OpenCV to open a Tiff file (big Tiff file) and split it on two different file with a mask like that [Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8631e.png), in the end the file 1 have pixel black and the file 2 have the negative - pixel white of the original image.

Any ideas or example for me?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the file, you can use the function [imread](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html). This stores it in a cv::Mat object. Since your mask is black and white, I would read the mask-image as a grayscale using IMREAD_GRAYSCALE. This gives you each pixel with a value from 0-255. That should cover the first part of your question.

I have to admit I am having trouble understandig your question, but I expect you want to create two images. The first contains all the pixels where your mask has a black pixel. The second one contains an image where in the mask all the pixels are white.
You could look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175114/opencv-image-multiplication). Additionally I would like to give you the way that I would do it.

The problem you would run in to is that your .tiff-image has a different type than your chessboard. Tiff is probably CV_8UC3 and chessboard is probably CV_8UC1. But this should be easily solvable.
I think you would probably want to look at each individual pixel and leave the be if, at that same pixel of the chessboard, your color is white. Then if it is not, make that pixel from your original pixel black. I have not tested this, but it would look something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalImage.rows; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < originalImage.cols; j++) {
    if (chessboard.at<uchar>(Point(j, i)) != 255) {
        originalImage.at<Vec3b>(Point(j, i)) = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

}

Scalar is used, since the originalImage has three channels instead of one. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create the mask:

```
cv::Mat tiff;
cv::Mat maskDark = tiff == 0; // comparison like '< 10' also works
cv::Mat maskDark = tiff == 255;
```